# How to define multiple text and formula in a cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Given,

```
       | A  | B   | C    |
Row 1  |xxx | 121 | 21.1 |
```

In a new **single** cell, how can I write formula that produces:

```
Some arbitrary text ...
The first column  = xxx
The second column = 121
The third column = 21.1
```

The parts that say "Some arbitrary text, The first column, The second column, The third column" are already in the cell. All I want to do is to just define a formula that does something like:

```
Some arbitrary text ...
The first column  = A1
The second column = B1
The third column = C1
```

Comment: While Excel and Google Sheets have similar features there are some that aren't the same, so choose one app. By the other hand, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the CONCATENATE() function

```
=CONCATENATE("some arbitrary text",CHAR(10),"The first column = ",A1,CHAR(10),"The second column = ",B1,CHAR(10),"The third column = ",C1)
```

or with out CONCATENATE.

```
="some arbitrary text"&CHAR(10)&"The first column = "&A1&CHAR(10)&"The second column = "&B1&CHAR(10)&"The third column = "&C1
```

Either way, the cell's `Wrap text` property must be set to True (check on the Format Cells dialog's -> Alignment tab).

The texts "First column = " etc. can't be already in the cell. They must be in the formula. However, if they are variable you might have them in another column or columns where they are hidden, and pull them into your formula via a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If A12 contains the new single line cell,

```
Some arbitrary text ...
The first column  = 
The second column = 
The third column =
```

B12:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(CHAR(10),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A12,CHAR(10), "", 1), CHAR(10))&A1:C1)),"", CHAR(10)))
```